# Rspec stubbing method for only specific arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to stub method for only specific arguments. Something like this

```
boss.stub(:fire!).with(employee1).and_return(true)
```

If any other employee is passed to `boss.fire!` method, I'll get `boss received unexpected message` error, but what I would really like is just to override the method for specific argument, and leave it be for all others.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can add a default stub for the `fire!` method which will call original implementation:

```
boss.stub(:fire!).and_call_original
boss.stub(:fire!).with(employee1).and_return(true)
```

Rspec 3 Syntax (@pk-nb)

```
allow(boss).to receive(:fire!).and_call_original
allow(boss).to receive(:fire!).with(employee1).and_return(true)
```

Comment: Same thing with RSpec 3 syntax:

`allow(boss).to receive(:fire!).and_call_original
allow(boss).to receive(:fire!).with(employee1).and_return(true)`

Comment: Note that, you cannot combine one generic `allow` with one specific `expect`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try write your own stubbing method, with code like this

```
fire_method = boss.method(:fire!)
boss.stub!(:fire!) do |employee|  
  if employee == employee1
    true
  else
    fire_method.call(*args)
  end
end
```