# How to test a mixed-in class method is being called with RSpec and Mocha?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, ruby-mocha

I have a module:

```rb
module MyModule
  def do_something
    # ...
  end
end
```

used by a class as follows:

```rb
class MyCommand
  extend MyModule

  def self.execute
    # ...
    do_something
  end
end
```

How do I verify that `MyCommand.execute` calls `do_something`?  I have tried partial mocking with mocha, but it doesn't fail when `do_something` is not called:

```
it "calls do_something" do
  MyCommand.stubs(:do_something)
  MyCommand.execute
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's *one* solution.

As I mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559374/mocha-stubbing-method-with-specific-parameter-but-not-for-other-parameters/16578496#16578496), there are two strategies to mocking/stubbing:

1) Using mocha's `expects` will auto-assert at the end of your test. In your case, it means if `MyCommand.execute` is not called after `expects`ing it, the test will fail.

2) The more specific/assertive way to do this is to use a combination of stubs and spies. The stub creates the fake object with the behavior you specify, then the spy check so to see if anyone called the method. To use your example (note this is RSpec):

```
require 'mocha'
require 'bourne'

it 'calls :do_something when .execute is run' do
  AnotherClass.stubs(:do_something)

  MyCommand.execute

  expect(AnotherClass).to have_received(:do_something)
end

# my_command.rb
class MyCommand
  def self.execute
    AnotherClass.do_something
  end
end
```

So the `expect` line uses [bourne](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourne)'s matcher to check and see if `:do_something` was called on `MyCommand.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, looks like `expects` is the solution:

```
it "calls do_something" do
  MyCommand.expects(:do_something)
  MyCommand.execute
end
```

Comment: just had this same question, can confirm that this answer allows me to accurately place an expectation for a class method to be called