# Mocha: Can I put a "never" expectation on a stubbed method WITH parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

My question is similar to this one: [Mocha: stubbing method with specific parameter but not for other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559374/mocha-stubbing-method-with-specific-parameter-but-not-for-other-parameters)

```
obj.expects(:do_something).with(:apples).never
perform_action_on_obj
```

The `perform_action_on_obj` will not call `do_something(:apples)` as I expect. However, it may call `do_something(:bananas)`. If it does, I get an unexpected invocation failure.

My understanding is that since I placed `never` at the end of the expectation, it only applied to that specific modified expectation. However it appears that once I start mocking behavior on `obj` I've "screwed it up" in a sense.

How can I allow other invocations of the `do_something` method on `obj`?

EDIT: Here is a clear cut example that demonstrates my issue perfectly:

```
describe 'mocha' do
  it 'drives me nuts' do
    a = mock()
    a.expects(:method_call).with(:apples)

    a.lol(:apples)
    a.lol(:bananas) # throws an unexpected invocation
  end 
end
```

Comment: You need to make sure if you are calling do_something(:bananas) that you have an expects(:do_something).with(:bananas)

Comment: Why? Why does mocha "take over" the method call. As soon as I mock a method call like that, it screws up everything else

Comment: I'm not quite following - are you hoping to call the method more than once without causing the error, or are you trying to assert that the method is never called with a given parameter?

Comment: Both. I want to assert the method is never called with a given parameter, while still allowing it to be called with other parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a workaround using [ParameterMatchers](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html):

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mocha/setup'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_something
    my_mock = mock()
    my_mock.expects(:blah).with(:apple).never
    my_mock.expects(:blah).with(Not equals :apple).at_least(0)
    my_mock.blah(:pear)
    my_mock.blah(:apple)
  end
end
```

Result:

```
>> ruby mocha_test.rb 
Run options: 

# Running tests:

F

Finished tests in 0.000799s, 1251.6240 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_something(MyTest) [mocha_test.rb:10]:
unexpected invocation: #<Mock:0xca0e68>.blah(:apple)
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected never, invoked once: #<Mock:0xca0e68>.blah(:apple)
satisfied expectations:
- allowed any number of times, invoked once: #<Mock:0xca0e68>.blah(Not(:apple))


1 tests, 0 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

In general, I agree with you: this behavior is frustrating to work with and violates the principle of least surprise.  It's also hard to extend the trick above to more general cases, since you'll have to write an increasingly complicated 'catchall' expression. If you want something more intuitive, I find [RSpec's mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) to be quite nice.

Comment: Nice. This gets me around the issue, but yeah certainly not elegant at all!

Answer (score 3):

have you tried the [block feature of `with`](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#with-instance_method)?

#### given that this:

```
obj.stubs(:do_something).with(:apples)
```

#### gives the same behavior as this:

```
obj.stubs(:do_something).with { |p| p == :apples }
```

#### you can flip the logic to get what you want:

```
obj.stubs(:do_something).with { |p| p != :apples }
```

calls to `do_something` with anything other than `:apples` will pass, whereas `obj.do_something(:apples)` will yield an unexpected invocation.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a hack than a real answer explaining mocha's behavior but perhaps the following will work?

```
obj.expects(:do_something).with(:apples).times(0)
```

Mocha will set the cardinality instance variable using [times rather than exactly](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/j/jferris-mocha-0.9.8.20100526112143/Mocha/Expectation.html).

Comment: Ah unfortunately that results in the same unexpected invocation errors when `obj.do_something(:bananas)` is called

Comment: Nuts.  Yeah I have no better ideas.  There is an answer somewhere in the Mocha source but it might be easier just to `expects(:do_something).with(:bananas)`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work form me, so I figured out this work around that does in my case.

```
class NeverError < StandardError; end

obj.stubs(:do_something).with(:apples).raises(NeverError)

obj.do_something(:bananas)

begin
  obj.do_something(:apples)
rescue NeverError
  assert false, "expected not to receive do_something with apples"
end
```

There's room for improvement, but this gives the gist and should be easy to modify to fit most scenarios.