# Mocking out file contents in ChefSpec

Tags: chefspec

I have a chef cookbook which copies the ubutunu user's (default user of the amazon AMI am using) authorized keys file to a newly created user.

```
ubuntu_public_key_file = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys"
file "#{new_user_homedir}/.ssh/authorized_keys" do
  owner new_user
  group new_user_group
  mode "0600"
  content IO.read(ubuntu_public_key_file)
end
```

Am trying out chefspec and I want to test this out. I want to mock the existence of ubuntu_public_key_file and its contents. Any feedback on this is appreciated!

Comment: a data bag would be a better place where to keep your public keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use RSpec stubs:

```rb
describe 'cookbook::recipe' do
  let(:content) do
    "CUSTOM SSH KEY CONTENT HERE"
  end

  before do
    IO.stub(:read).with('/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys').and_return(content)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I got the below error  
expected: ("/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys")
got: ("/home/kenji/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448-railsexpress@global/gems/fauxhai-2.0.1/lib/fauxhai/platforms/ubuntu/12.04.json")"
Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
 
I don't think I want to stub the default behaviour but just this file.read. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks! This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972964/rspec-stubbing-method-for-only-specific-arguments helped :-)